# BSD `sed`: running multi-command `sed` script from within a shell: replace Nth occurrence

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have plain BSD SED (non GNU).
This is what I am running. It's failing on the last `sed` command. Errors are: string is longer then 8 chars; and Label N is invalid or something like that.
This is not the whole code - just part that fails:

```
 set -x
        chg ()
        {
        file=$1

sed ":1 
N 
$!b1 
s/)/,col1)/5 "  $file > tmp && mv tmp $file 
}

 chg $f

sed: 0602-404 Function N  cannot be parsed for both above and below
```

I tried

```
 set -x
        chg ()
        {
        file=$1

sed ': 1 \
 N \
 $!b1 \
 s/)/,col1)/5'  $file > tmp && mv tmp $file 
}

 chg $f
```

**The same command will work in command line**

```
   sed ': 1  <enter>
N  <enter> etc
```

How do ya fix this ?
I want 5th occurrence of `)` to be replaced by `,col )` ,

```
sed -e $':x\nN;$!bx\ns/)/,col1)/5'
```

thanks. Above  1 liner did not work 
 for some reason the last bit `/5` on sed on-liners never work for me on AIX 
Input

```
#more sdat
) from  ( d , bd  , c , d blah
someblah, blah ) as
somebla, lah )
as
(some other pos )
dada
```

Output

```
sed -e ':x' -e 'N;$!bx' -e 's/)/,col1)/5' sdat

) from  ( d , bd  , c , d blah
someblah, blah ) as
somebla, lah )
as
(some other pos )
dada

<br>
```

Comment: Does your script execute the same `sed` as you do on the command line? What is the output from `set -x`?  What is the *precise* error message?

Comment: Tangentially, you should use double quotes around any variable which contains a file name.

Comment: Also spaces are not permitted between the colon and the label. It should be `:1` instead of `: 1`. Another problem might be the spaces you're putting in front of each line in the first example.

Comment: I fixed all these things : added `"` removed the spaces `: 1` to `:1`  and beginning of the line space still stuck here  with the 1st one giving me `sed: 0602-404 Function N  cannot be parsed.`

Comment: Post concise, testable, sample input and expected output and we can help you. The right solution will NOT be in sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the following successfully:

```
function chg {
  sed ':x
N 
$!bx
s/)/,col1)/5 '
}
```

Notice that I replaced your double-quotes with single quotes, and your label `1` with `x`.  Also, please note that no space is allowed after `bx`.

With this script the following input produces the output shown below:

```
 (a)(b)
 (c) (d) (e) (f) (g)
```

Output:

```
(a)(b)
(c) (d) (e,col1) (f) (g)
```

The `sed` used:

```
 man sed | tail -n 1
 BSD                              May 10, 2005                              BSD
```

p.s. In bash, the sed command can be turned into a one-liner that works with BSD sed as follows:

```
sed -e $':x\nN;$!bx\ns/)/,col1)/5'
```

Comment: Good stuff. Note that you can single-line this  without bash by making sure that your labels are at the end of their own command string. `sed -e ':x' -e 'N;$!bx' -e 's/)/,col1)/5'`

Comment: @ghoti - Good point.  I think it further undercuts the claim made above that "The right solution will NOT be in sed."  What do you think?

Comment: Erm...  I'm afraid you can't bait me to disagree with Ed Morton.  :-D  A sed-based solution bay *work*, and it may be *good enough*, but ... "right"?  No.  The right solution is always one that understands the *format* of the input data, and changes it according to its structure, and sed cannot do that. That said, "good enough" is often ... good enough.

Comment: for some reason the last part on that 1 Liner wont work for me and I read some place that the Match the Nth Instance implementation of `sed` has had variations. Referring to the `5` in this `sed -e ':x' -e 'N;$!bx' -e 's/)/,col1)/5' `that is why I was so stuck.But hang on ..it may work because you are putting the whole thing in buffer and then doing the Nth instance logic>Thank You